# Generate preview images with custom text?

Tags: php, image, web, dynamic-image-generation, image-generation

I´m working on a webshop where you can personalize Glasses, Pens etc. with gravures...

We also want a "Preview" function like in this shop (click on "Vorschau"):
https://www.geschenke-online.de/graviertes-whiskyglas-scotch-whiskey-drinker-mit-wunschname-und-geburtsjahr

They are generating the preview images through this link: 
https://hotrod-factory.com/cgi-bin/webproducer?motiv=pde-leo-k18-whg25.dtm&text_field1=Mytext%20&text_field2=2015&width=600

**What is a .dtm file and how can I implement this feature on my website?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are using a custom program (a cgi script is like a program) called webproducer to render that preview. The .dtm extension is meaningless, those requests are being responded as images.

Comment: It may be a custom made program, cgi-bin is just a name that identifies a specific kind of programs. To start rendering text into images I'd recommend you start looking at Imagemagick: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/annotating/ this tutorial is for using it from the command line but you could use it as a library and/or automate that from PHP. For fancier 3D projections you may need to use some specialized rendering software that could be automated.